# How to initiate a Gmail search from the addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I can view the search results through the `GmailApp` service. Which can be achieved through the following code:

`var threads = GmailApp.search('from:github');`

However, this would not affect the UI, since it is only the add-on performing the query. I would like to perform a search in the add-on and the search results must be seen in the Gmail application.

Comment: The application is on Google's servers - not the device.

Comment: Is there any service to access the search ?

Comment: I don't understand your question - you already know how to search Gmail through a Gmail add-on, via `GmailApp.search(....)`. What other search are you trying to access? Please ask a good, detailed question that clearly states your issue and your research!

Comment: I have the search results when I user GmailApp. But I would like the gmail's UI to reflect to search which I had performed. I would like to do this at a click of a button through my addon.

Comment: No, add-ons have no ability to alter the actual application.

Comment: Currently I am able to control Gmail's compose, and reply actions. Add-ons allow us to do this. Hence the thought .

Comment: File a feature request for additional `Action` types: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:325133