# Open a draft email after creating it

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I would like to know if there is the possibility to open a draft directly after it's creation. After getting a file in a distant server, I would create an empty draft and I would like to open the draft message, so that I can fill it.

Here is my current code, the draft is well created, but I haven't found a way to open it. I need to navigate to "Drafts" section to open it.

```js
var responseDownload = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlDownload, params);    
    
var theFile = Utilities.newBlob(responseDownload)
  .setName(json.entry.name)
  .setContentTypeFromExtension();

var recipient = "";
var subject = "";
var body = "\n\nThis draft was automatically generated.";
var options = 
    {
      attachments: [theFile]
    };
  
  var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, subject, body, options);
```

Comment: how are you invoking the code you show here? https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/compose

Comment: This is the result of an action attached to a button when I click on "Send this file", this function is invoked.

Comment: Is this useful for your situation? You can retrieve the created draft using ``GmailApp.getDrafts()``. And also you can retrieve each message of drafts and update it. You can see the detail information at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question. Unfortunately , CardService is the only way to create addons and it does not control the GmailUI except for opening a compose popup.

You may refer to this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719814/how-to-initiate-a-gmail-search-from-the-addon) as well.

**Update:** To open a compose popup :

```
function renderComposeMail(e) {
// Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes, in this case to allow
// a reply to be drafted.
var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(e.parameters.senderEmail, "subject", "body");
var card = CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder().setGmailDraft(draft);
return card.build();}
```

Call this method on button click ,or any desired event.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it asap :)

Comment: It's working well, but only with an action like this :
var button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Reply')
    .setComposeAction(action, CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT);

Thanks for your help !

Comment: REPLY_AS_DRAFT will reply to the same thread , though. Is that OK ?

Comment: This is a very good point, I just changed to "STANDALONE_DRAFT" since I ask the user if he wants to create an empty draft or make an reply, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function create_draft_mail_and_get_url() {
    var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(e.parameters.senderEmail, "subject", "body");
    var draft_Id = draft.getMessage().getId();
    var email_Url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=" + draft_Id;
    return email_Url;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).